Ionic github action apk 'Unable to launch Android Studio'
I am trying to build an apk from a ionic project using github action.
I created a fresh ionic project with angular.
name: Build Android

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build APK
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout source
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 20.x

      - name: Install Ionic
        run: npm install -g @ionic/cli

      - name: Install app dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Build Ionic App
        run: ionic build

      - name: Copy Android
        run: ionic capacitor copy android

      - name: Build Android Dev APK
        run: ionic capacitor build android

      - name: Build Android Release APK
        run: ionic capacitor build android --release --prod

      - name: Generate the Android App Bundle
        working-directory: ./android/
        run: ./gradlew bundle

      - name: Upload dev APK
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: app-dev
          path: apk/app-debug.apk

      - name: Upload release bundle
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: app-release
          path: apk/app.aab


The Build Android Dev APK and Build Android Release APK steps are failing
Here is the logs:
[capacitor] ✔ update android in 61.72ms
[capacitor] [info] Sync finished in 0.144s
[INFO] Ready for use in your Native IDE!
       
       To continue, build your project using Android Studio!
> capacitor open android
Error: [capacitor] [error] Unable to launch Android Studio. Is it installed?
[capacitor]         Attempted to open Android Studio at: /usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
[capacitor]         You can configure this with the CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH environment variable.

Then the last step Generate the Android App Bundle is having this error, but i suppose I would need to fix the first error before:
Run ./gradlew bundle
/home/runner/work/_temp/f9bad4ef-d4dc-4d4f-905e-2efdacfa35b5.sh: line 1: ./gradlew: Permission denied
Error: Process completed with exit code 126.

How can I install android studio inside github action ?
